# getFieldValue failed when attempting dedup

Tags: dedup, fatal

I'm getting this error when attempting to dedup our contacts, on Civi 5.64.4, WP 6.4.3. Any pointers are appreciated.

```
***ERROR***
message:            getFieldValue failed
code:               
exception:          CRM_Core_Exception Object
(
[errorData:CRM_Core_Exception:private] => Array
    (
        [error_code] => 0
    )

[cause:protected] =>
[_trace:PEAR_Exception:private] =>
[message:protected] => getFieldValue failed
[string:Exception:private] =>
[code:protected] => 0
[file:protected] => /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php
[line:protected] => 1417
[trace:Exception:private] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [file] => /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Dedupe/BAO/DedupeRuleGroup.php
                [line] => 594
                [function] => getFieldValue
                [class] => CRM_Core_DAO
                [type] => ::
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [file] => /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Dedupe/Merger.php
                [line] => 2249
                [function] => getContactTypeForRuleGroup
                [class] => CRM_Dedupe_BAO_DedupeRuleGroup
                [type] => ::
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [file] => /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Page/DedupeFind.php
                [line] => 98
                [function] => getMergeCacheKeyString
                [class] => CRM_Dedupe_Merger
                [type] => ::
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [file] => /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php
                [line] => 319
                [function] => run
                [class] => CRM_Contact_Page_DedupeFind
                [type] => ->
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [file] => /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php
                [line...

***LAST ERROR***


***LOGGED IN USER***
contact_id:         102
display_name:       twowheeler
email_id:           26354
email:              hideuser@thehcpac.org
id:                 102

REMOTE_ADDR: 172.70.111.132
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: 72.72.162.120
HTTP_USER_AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:124.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/124.0


***SERVER***
SERVER_SOFTWARE:    Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)
REQUEST_URI:        /wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontact%2Fdedupefind
HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:
HTTPS:              on
SSL_TLS_SNI:        thehcpac.org
HTTP_HOST:          thehcpac.org
HTTP_CONNECTION:    Keep-Alive
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING:gzip, br
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR:72.72.162.120
HTTP_CF_RAY:        868f40ceed581899-EWR
CONTENT_LENGTH:     356
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO:https
HTTP_CF_VISITOR:    {\"scheme\":\"https\"}
HTTP_USER_AGENT:    Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:124.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/124.0
HTTP_ACCEPT:        text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE:en-US,en;q=0.5
HTTP_REFERER:       https://thehcpac.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontact%2Fdedupefind&reset=1&rgid=15&action=preview
CONTENT_TYPE:       application/x-www-form-urlencoded
HTTP_ORIGIN:        https://thehcpac.org
HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS:1
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST:document
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_MODE:navigate
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE:same-origin
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_USER:?1
HTTP_SEC_GPC:       1
HTTP_COOKIE:        wordpress_sec_e339517222a676ebe445783c89e39752=hideuser%7C1711281978%7CHV1ERL3iRu6L2DRJNtIIYnTKgX84DFUZFF1VMszRUKX%7C4ecb97d47cf3373deadfee0dfb3c87d3e3c38f88b6d9c60752be29238fdb852b; cf_clearance=mdGH2Z_dfCvGnxH9iqiuJaBYYp5aJ7Daug9lUM.SU9o-1711205237-1.0.1.1-hh3GpIKge0NS8yzGC7vLt5YlsQ1WGjM8ur0wPTs5yfdeihHsCepPdekH6hKmiDtIEWqz0MEP1zdyFdYPQmzBzw; wp-settings-1=imgsize%3Dmedium%26ampeditor%3Dtinymce%26amplibraryContent%3Dbrowse%26ampurlbutton%3Dcustom%26ampadvImgDetails%3Dshow%26amppost_dfw%3Doff%26amphidetb%3D1%26ampalign%3Dleft%26ampeditor_plain_text_paste_warning%3D2%26ampmfold%3Do%26ampuploader%3D1%26ampcats%3Dpop%26libraryContent%3Dbrowse%26align%3Dleft%26editor%3Dtinymce%26urlbutton%3Dnone%26hidetb%3D1;
wp-settings-time-1=1710349956; PHPSESSID=m0ld981tur807gg20l0dtivldt; sbjs_migrations=1418474375998%3D1; sbjs_current_add=fd%3D2024-03-22%2021%3A22%3A52%7C%7C%7Cep%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fthehcpac.org%2Fnite-at-the-races%2F%7C%7C%7Crf%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2F; sbjs_first_add=fd%3D2024-03-20%2011%3A59%3A08%7C%7C%7Cep%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fthehcpac.org%2F%7C%7C%7Crf%3D%28none%29; sbjs_current=typ%3Dreferral%7C%7C%7Csrc%3Dmail.google.com%7C%7C%7Cmdm%3Dreferral%7C%7C%7Ccmp%3D%28none%29%7C%7C%7Ccnt%3D%2F%7C%7C%7Ctrm%3D%28none%29%7C%7C%7Cid%3D%28none%29; sbjs_first=typ%3Dtypein%7C%7C%7Csrc%3D%28direct%29%7C%7C%7Cmdm%3D%28none%29%7C%7C%7Ccmp%3D%28none%29%7C%7C%7Ccnt%3D%28none%29%7C%7C%7Ctrm%3D%28none%29%7C%7C%7Cid%3D%28none%29;
sbjs_udata=vst%3D5%7C%7C%7Cuip%3D%28none%29%7C%7C%7Cuag%3DMozilla%2F5.0%20%28X11%3B%20Ubuntu%3B%20Linux%20x86_64%3B%20rv%3A124.0%29%20Gecko%2F20100101%20Firefox%2F124.0; wordpress_logged_in_e339517222a676ebe445783c89e39752=hideuser%7C1711281978%7CHV1ERL3iRu6L2DRJNtIIYnTKgX84DFUZFF1VMszRUKX%7C0c47e5831cee1d9bd3bad211ef618a3c47507b31251e32dceb3a9d219a0cd856; po_assigned_roles[0]=administrator; tk_ai=woo%3A%2BJtu1CoogwOOrBj0lGBcT7Ei; wordpress_test_cookie=WP%20Cookie%20check; wp_lang=en_US; wp_woocommerce_session_e339517222a676ebe445783c89e39752=1%7C%7C17...
HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP:72.72.162.120
HTTP_CDN_LOOP:      cloudflare
HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY:  US
PATH:               /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
SERVER_SIGNATURE:   <address>Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) Server at thehcpac.org Port 443</address>

SERVER_NAME:        thehcpac.org
SERVER_ADDR:        45.56.101.158
SERVER_PORT:        443
REMOTE_ADDR:        172.70.111.132
DOCUMENT_ROOT:      /var/www/html
REQUEST_SCHEME:     https
CONTEXT_PREFIX:     
CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT:/var/www/html
SERVER_ADMIN:       hideuser@thehcpac.org
SCRIPT_FILENAME:    /var/www/html/wp-admin/admin.php
REMOTE_PORT:        38674
GATEWAY_INTERFACE:  CGI/1.1
SERVER_PROTOCOL:    HTTP/1.1
REQUEST_METHOD:     POST
QUERY_STRING:       page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontact%2Fdedupefind
SCRIPT_NAME:        /wp-admin/admin.php
PHP_SELF:           /wp-admin/admin.php
REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT: 1711205629.2812
REQUEST_TIME:       1711205629



***BACKTRACE***
#0 /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/extensions/ca.bidon.reporterror/CRM/ReportError/Utils.php(31): reporterror_civicrm_generatereport("HCPAC", (Array:3), NULL, (Array:0))
#1 /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/extensions/ca.bidon.reporterror/CRM/ReportError/Handler/FormsNoReferer.php(58): CRM_ReportError_Utils::sendReport((Array:3), (Array:0))
#2 /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/extensions/ca.bidon.reporterror/reporterror.php(130): CRM_ReportError_Handler_FormsNoReferer::handler((Array:3), (Array:0))
#3 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(431): reporterror_civicrm_handler((Array:3))
#4 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(39): CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException(Object(CRM_Core_Exception))
#5 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1199): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#6 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#7 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
#8 /var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#9 /var/www/html/wp-admin/admin.php(259): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
#10 {main}
```

Comment: Do you have `rgid=xx` in the URL? If not, which rule have you selected for merging the contacts? Can you try appending `rgid=<dedupe_rule_id>` as a query string in case it fixes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this was caused by a conflict with another plugin. Solved with the awesome "Freesoul Deactivate Plugins" to isolate them from each other.